# How to get +- 400 volt DC from two sources?

Tags: series, bridge-rectifier

I tried two rectifiers in series. From 230V AC I get on each rectifier 207V DC.
If I linked them in series + to - it seems to me that the direct current flows into the AC supply.

How can I configure it to supply me +-400 volt DC?

I am using 600V 50 ampere rectifiers from two inverters and want to supply a drive with 400 volt DC.

[image: Two rectifiers in series]

Comment: two separate transformers? This isn't two sources, it's the same source twice. But if you have a transformer you don't need two separate sources, you can just put twice as many turns on the transformer and double the voltage that way.

Comment: also if you can't see why this doesn't work then I'm not sure you should be playing with 400 volts.

Comment: Rectifying 230VAC should result to capacitor being charged to 325V. I wonder how are you able to get a measurement of 207V out of it. Are you measuring the rectified AC but without the capacitor? This could  maybe solved by using caps and the rectifiers in a voltage doubler config, but that would result into 625V being charged to caps so it would exceed 400V and also the 600V ratings of the rectifier, so don't try that unless you get right components first.

Comment: Please don't work with even 60V if you do not understand. It can't be understated how super super basic this is and you are going to get hurt.

Comment: All your diodes are drawn backwards according to the '+' and '-' signs on your bridge rectifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has to explain it.

When you connect that (+) and (-) of the middle, the two "nodes", it "effectively" shorts (+) and (-) of the rectified DC, but, unlike batteries, it does not stack up individual DC. If you can draw a continuous line that current can go through, from one end of the AC wire  to another end (line, hot & neutral), that makes a ["circuit" (on dictionary: something shaped approximately like a circle,that starts and ends in the same place.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/circuit)), that leads a voltage to meet a different voltage at a point (ends in the same place). When two extreme difference meet, it is a "short circuit", can blow the fuse, otherwise, it can cause many other troubles that involve "hazards", including fire and personal injury, or death.

[image]

The voltage multiplier, people are talking about, is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler), and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson_multiplier).

I was doing the same, trying to boost the voltage, when I was 8, using live 100V lines. My father (an educator) did not stop me experimenting "nonsense", but watched me and explained when I asked questions.

That was still dangerous, but, you are using 230V. 
**You must have some knowledgeable grownups to watch your experiment. Otherwise, you can end up in [serious situation](https://www.platinumelectricians.com.au/blog/8-dangerous-home-electrical-hazards/), and cause of [death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury).**

Answer (score 0):

> I tried two rectifiers in series. From 230V AC I get on each rectifier 207V DC.

1. You need to draw your diodes correctly. In your drawing they are reversed according to your + and - terminals.
2. You need to show where you measured 207 V.

> If I linked them in series + to - it seems to me that the direct current flows into the AC supply.

No. It will alternately short circuit as shown by the red and blue paths in Figure 1. Either the fuse will blow (you do have one, don't you?) or the diodes will melt.

> How can I configure it to supply me +-400 volt DC?

You can't. The most you can get from rectified 230 V mains is \$ 230 \sqrt 2 \$ V = 325 V. This is covered in any good tutorial on mains power supplies.

> I am using 600V 50 ampere rectifiers from two inverters and want to supply a drive with 400 volt DC.

You can't do it this way.

[image]

*Figure 1. When live wire is positive you have a short-circuit as shown in red. When live wire is negative you have a short-circuit as shown in blue.*

These are dangerous voltages. You have not shown enough understanding of what you are doing to propose any solution for you.